# django how to insert a textbox input to sqlite database?

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I apologize for asking a newbie question. I know both python and sqlite, but I never worked with them for a website with django framework.

So for example, my database already has 2 fields A and B. I want to insert dataA and dataB to A and B respectively. I want to take the input from 2 textbox on my website and put these data into the database as an entry.

How can I do that? If this is not too easy, where can I find in the documentation about this information?

Comment: In the tutorial, naturally. Part 4 talks about forms, but looks like you need to do the whole thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sounds like you can use ModelForm for this purpose.

Just create your models like so:

```
class YourModel(models.Model):
    textA = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    textB = models.CharField(max_length=200,)
    ...
```

Then, create your form:

```
class YourModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = YourModel
        fields = ['textA', 'textB']
        ...
```

Then, reference this from your view:

```
class YourCreateView(CreateView):
    form_class  = YourModelForm
```

Render this in your template (`{{ form }}}`) and you're done (mostly)!

Comment: Where is the part I update this entry in the database?

Comment: It depends on how you'd like to do that. For example, if you need this to be done by users, you might change the `CreateView` to `UpdateView`. Or, you might use the Django Admin for staff updates. Or, just change the data via the shell using the Django ORM.